# Getting rid of the space in heading (HTML, CSS related)

Tags: html, css

Just wondering how to get rid of the unnecessary looking spaces 
in my heading. I want my header to look similar to the capture 2 (2nd picture) but there are unnecessary spaces that I can't seem to get rid of. I ran it through jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yT6h6/ and I can still see the spaces even though I don't think there was anything wrong with the code. Please take a look at this and greatly appreciated if you can help me.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="heading"><b style="font-size:14px; font-family:'Arial', Gadget, sans-serif"><b style="font-size:9px;"><a href="default.html" class="link5">Home \\</a> <a href="current_students.html" class="link5">Current Students \\</a></b>
</b>
        <br />FBE Degrees &amp; Electives
        <br>
<span class="style11">FBE Degrees &amp; Other Courses for FBE students including Elective courses</span> 
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.heading {
    height: auto;
    width: 525px;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #DBDBDB;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
.content {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 575px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style11 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #336666;
}
a.link5:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.link5:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.link5:hover {
    color: #E9E8C7;
}
a.link5:active {
    color: #E9E8C7;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you want to remove space from top and bottom side right?

Comment: I tried your code I do not see any spaces ...

Comment: @Fox really? it seems like only I see the space? see the picture provided and you can see that there are space between the header "FBE Degrees & Electives" and the small information saying "Fbe degrees & other courses for FBE students including Elective courses"

Comment: @Nilesh I want to remove the space between the words (the heading which says FBE Degrees & Electives and the small info below")

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help!  I did that, still looks the same.. hmm..

Answer (score 0):

try this one remove line-height and add display:block

```
 .style11 { 
   font-size: 10px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   display:block;
  color: #336666;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I wanted :( I wanted to reduce the gap between the actual heading 'FBE Degree & Elective' and the small info below, similar to the 2nd picture provided (with the heading B Architectural Studies)

Comment: try to remove line-height: 15px; from .style11 css class
and aa display:block; in .style11 class

Comment: Thanks! that worked in some ways! is it possible to do the same between the "home \\ current students " option and the heading? I tried adding the  display:block to them but the heading is now much bigger...

Comment: yes here you can set line-height in line <b> tag of "home current" pixel according to your require. like below 

<b style="font-size: 14px; line-height:3px;......

Comment: Added that in but the line-height code doesn't seem to be functioning at all. Still the same with or without it even though, the dreamweaver design shows that it's changed, when I run it through browsers, still the same..

Comment: its working fine with line height in <b> in my firefox and chorme.

Comment: Hmm, could it be browser problem? I edited in this code 

<div class="heading"><b style="font-size:14px line-height:3px; font-family:'Arial', Gadget, sans-serif "><b style="font-size:9px; line-height:3px;"><a href="default.html" class="link5">Home \\</a> <a href="current_students.html" class="link5">Current Students \\</a></b>

Answer (score 0):

Hey i've tried your code see at: http://jsbin.com/awonek/1/edit

Looks fine to me.

could code try

```
div#heading{
      margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```

what browsers have you tried it in?

Added some changes: See http://jsbin.com/uvurev/1/edit

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="heading">
        <a href="default.html" class="link5">Home \\ </a> <a href="current_students.html" class="link5">Current Students \\ </a>
        <h2 class="M_logo_text">FBE Degrees &amp; Electives</h2>
        <span class="style11">FBE Degrees &amp; Other Courses for FBE students including Elective courses</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.heading {
    height: auto;
    width: 525px;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: #DBDBDB;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
.content {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 575px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style11 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #336666;
}
a.link5{
    font-size:9px; font-family:'Arial', Gadget, sans-serif
    margin-right: -2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.link5:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.link5:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.link5:hover {
    color: #E9E8C7;
}
a.link5:active {
    color: #E9E8C7;
}

/*
added style
*/
b.type1{
    font-size:9px; font-family:'Arial', Gadget, sans-serif
}
h2.M_logo_text{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yep! It actually looks fine in Dreamweaver design but when I actually run it through both firefox and IE, it goes like that...

Comment: I'll run this in other browsers an get back to you, there is a solution just need to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you firstly need to seriously tidy up that HTML and use some more natural elements. The heading should be a H of some level, probably h1. The paragraph tags make more sense for the text. Everything will be far cleaner and easier to solve if you do this. Here's my suggestion that changes the HTML and fixes your margin issues.

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="heading">
        <p class="crumbs"><a href="default.html" class="link5">Home \\</a>  <a href="current_students.html" class="link5">Current Students \\</a></p>
         <h1>FBE Degrees &amp; Electives</h1>

        <p class="subheading">FBE Degrees &amp; Other Courses for FBE students including Elective courses</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #336666;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.heading {
    background:#333333;
    padding:20px; 
}
.heading p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:10px;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size:28px;
    line-height:36px;
    color:#DBDBDB;
}
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yT6h6/6/

It can be simplified more actually (I left some of your classes in there even though they aren't used), but this is at least a lot neater to work with.